# theory of ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

i am looking for books more "theoretical" about ODE's with non trivial examples or at least some solutions to some exercises. Not techniques for solve or application, but things like maximal solutions, orbits, trajetories,poincaré theorem, Lyapunov.

Im having sooo much problem in this course, i believe this is mostly because literally every example in my textbook is complely trivial.

Ps: i already saw multiple posts requesting book for ODE's here, but i didnt find any of them having what i need.

Comment: [this](https://www.amazon.com/Ordinary-Differential-Equations-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486472116) is pretty good.

Comment: Maybe you already looked at these questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029646/book-recommendation-for-ordinary-differential-equations, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902681/second-course-on-odes-self-study-book-recommendation?